# What's the difference between "life conditions" and "living conditions"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives

What's the difference between *life conditions* and *living conditions*? I often use the former. "The life conditions of the Victorian workers", for example.

Answer (score 18):

"Living conditions" refers to the circumstances of a person's life—shelter, food, clothing, safety, access to clean water, and such. I don't think "life conditions" is an idiomatic phrase. An alternative might be "conditions for life," which refers to circumstances needed for physical or biological life to exist—water, energy, a suitable environment, and such.

Answer (score 8):

If there is a distinction then

- living conditions = *conditions under which you live*
- life conditions = *conditions under which you are alive*, though other phrases like 'conditions for life' are more common

> "This relative paucity of species in the chalk formation may be due in part to **unfavorable life conditions** in the area where chalk was being deposited, or to unfavorable conditions of preservation, or to both".
>  
>    -  CH Dane, WG Pierce & JB Reeside: The Stratigraphy of the Uppper Crethaceous Rocks North of the Arkasas River in Eastern Colorado([1937](http://books.google.com/books?id=2YrnAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA36&dq=%22life%20conditions%22&hl=sv&sa=X&ei=gWuSUojKJYiKywPLqICgAg&ved=0CHIQ6AEwBg))

Answer (score 2):

"Living conditions" is a much more common (about 100:1 on Google Books Ngram Viewer) than "life conditions" way of expressing your idea.

Comment: Do you mean to say that it's not wrong then? Can I still use it instead of the other or do you perceive that as a mistake in the usage of the language?

Comment: They mean the same thing, but because "living conditions" is the common idiom, it would sound natural where the other would sound strange.

Answer (score 0):

*Life conditions* is used in the social sciences, taken from Björn Kraus, as quoted in the entry for [Lifeworld](https://wikivisually.com/wiki/Lifeworld) on the WikiVisually website:

> "*Life conditions mean a person's material and immaterial circumstances of life.*
>
> *Lifeworld means a person's subjective construction of reality, which he or she forms under the condition of his or her life circumstances.*"